# How can I simplify an Irrational Fractional Expression in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, number-representation

The expression is:

$$\frac{4\surd3 + 5\surd2}{\surd48 + \surd18}$$

and its simplification is:

$$\frac{3}{5} + \frac{4\surd6}{15}$$

How can I perform such simplification in Mathematica?

Comment: Try `RootReduce` in combination with `Expand`. Next time please have in mind to write your code in the Mathematica form, to enable the easy copy/pasting it.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch  Using `Expand[RootReduce[ex]]`, where `ex` is the expression to be simplified, I obtain `3/5 + (4 Sqrt[2/3])/5`, which is not the same as the target expression.  By the way, `FullSimplify[ex]` yields `1/15 (9 + 4 Sqrt[6])`, which is simpler (as measured by `LeafCount`) than the target expression.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, so did I. However, the transformation from `3/5 + (4 Sqrt[2/3])/5` to the desired form is obvious, and the OP did not even give the copy-pastable expression. Therefore, I limited myself by a mere advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
(4 Sqrt[3] + 5 Sqrt[2])/(Sqrt[48] + Sqrt[18]) // FullSimplify
```

Out= $\frac{1}{15} \left(4 \sqrt{6}+9\right)$

or

```
(4 Sqrt[3] + 5 Sqrt[2])/(Sqrt[48] + Sqrt[18]) // FullSimplify // Expand
```

Out = $ \frac{4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}}{5}+\frac{3}{5}$